# which function is very fast to get html code in vb.net?

Tags: html, vb.net, performance, function, http

I am using vb.net and making some desktop software.Sometime i use HttpWebRequest and WebClient to get html of any web page but it's slow.
So,I want to know that have vb.net any function which will be very fast to get only HTML code from a web page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: I have similar issue. And I am wondering if my telephone cable is too thin and this is why everything is so slow...?? I heard that fiber optic can make for a fast data transmitting device.